# How to find the bottleneck in gradient computation in tensorflow

Tags: python, c, tensorflow

I am computing the gradients in a tape in tensorflow like so:

```
grad_l_model = l_tape.gradient(l_loss, l_vars)
```

However, the computation is taking forever. So I want to see what is it in the computation, whether it's the computation of the gradients of certain variables that's taking a long time. How can I do that?

Comment: the computation of gradients doesn't depend on the learning rate

Comment: You should provide more code (model , loss function..)